# Result of serialize()

Tags: php, jquery

maybe someone can explain me why the following code do a output with backslahes etc.

```
The Ajax-Call is
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'system/ajx/form_generator.php?ajx=1',
      data: $('#formstep').serialize(),
      success: function(result){
      $('#formarea').html(result);
      }
  });
```

The Html is

```
<form id="formstep" action="">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Ich suche</label>
<select id="produktgruppe" class="sselect" data-validation-error-msg="Bitte wählen Sie eine Gruppe aus" data-validation="required" name="produktgruppe">
<option></option>
<option value="1"">Büromöbel</option>
<option value="2"">Büro- & Schreibwaren</option>
<option value="3"">Druckerzubehör</option>
<option value="4"">Geschenkartikel</option>
</select>
</div>
</form>
```

And the result in my `php` file for `print_r($_POST)` is that

```
1 ) produktgruppe->1\\\"
```

Why he add the `\` and the `"` ?

Comment: because of extra `"` in your option values. remove them and will work fine.

Comment: ;-) it seems it is to late for me - thanks a lot ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your each option `value` attribute have one extra `"` and that's why you are getting strange output in your code so remove them like below:-

```
<form id="formstep" action="">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Ich suche</label>
<select id="produktgruppe" class="sselect" data-validation-error-msg="Bitte wählen Sie eine Gruppe aus" data-validation="required" name="produktgruppe">
<option></option>
<option value="1">Büromöbel</option><!-- remove extra `"` -->
<option value="2">Büro- & Schreibwaren</option><!-- remove extra `"` -->
<option value="3">Druckerzubehör</option><!-- remove extra `"` -->
<option value="4">Geschenkartikel</option><!-- remove extra `"` -->
</select>
</div>
</form>
```